# prevent default for all links inside a div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a div that looks like:

```
<div id="blah"> <a href="#" >hello</a>   <a href="#"> world</a></div>
```

I want to disable all the links inside this div using e.preventDefault();

How can I select all href tags that are inside the div id="blah" using jquery?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following will get you all `<a>` elements inside `<div>` with id blah  that have a `href` attribute defined.

```
$('#blah a[href]').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

without jQuery, something like the following *(I've obviously been living in jQuery world far too long as I originally had preventDefault in the vanilla JavaScript. Unfortunately, not cross-browser :( )* I did test this in Firefox, IE and Chrome

```
var anchors = document.getElementById('blah').getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i=0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    addEvent(anchors[i], 'click', preventDefault);
}

function preventDefault(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
   (e.preventDefault)? 
       e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
}

function addEvent(obj, evType, fn){ 
   if (obj.addEventListener){ 
       obj.addEventListener(evType, fn, false); 
       return true; 
   } 
   else if (obj.attachEvent){ 
       var r = obj.attachEvent("on"+evType, fn); 
       return r; 
 } else { 
       return false; 
 } 
}
```

For interest, this is how [jQuery](http://jquery.com) implements `preventDefault()`

```
// jQuery.Event is based on DOM3 Events as specified by the ECMAScript Language Binding
// http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20030331/ecma-script-binding.html
jQuery.Event.prototype = {
    preventDefault: function() {
        this.isDefaultPrevented = returnTrue;

        var e = this.originalEvent;
        if( !e )
            return;
        // if preventDefault exists run it on the original event
        if (e.preventDefault)
            e.preventDefault();
        // otherwise set the returnValue property of the original event to false (IE)
        e.returnValue = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#blah a').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

Non-jQuery ( I did not test this ):

```
    var addEvent = (function() {
    function addEventIE(el, ev, fn) {
        return el.attachEvent('on' + ev, function(e) {
        return fn.call(el, e);
        });
    }
    function addEventW3C(el, ev, fn) {
        return el.addEventListener(ev, fn, false);
    }
    return window.addEventListener ? addEventW3C:addEventIE;
    })();

var anchors = document.getElementById('blah').getElementsByTagName('a');
for ( var i = anchors.length; i--; ) {
    addEvent( anchors[i], 'click', function(e) { 
        e = e || window.event;
        if ( e.preventDefault ) e.preventDefault()
        else e.returnValue = false
    });
}
```