# Javascript code to preventDefault for all <a href> links

Tags: javascript, ajax, preventdefault

I am trying to get URLs to change using only Javascript, by updating the content via AJAX.

This is to prevent certain content (namely music, chat message boxes, etc) from refreshing and either

1. Clearing the place where your music is playing
2. Resetting something you are working on, like typing a message.

I just began today trying to implement something like this, and so far I've got this:

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('a')
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
   a[i].addEventListener('click',function(event){event.preventDefault();};
}
return false
```

However, this code

1. Doesn't allow the url to be changed
2. Doesn't load the AJAX.

My question is: how do I cancel the age from refreshing, but still allow the url to change?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` is faster than `querySelectorAll`. And avoid inline functions inside loops, at each iteration you create a duplicate function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
    ajax;
for (var i=0; i<a.length; ++i) {
   a[i].addEventListener('click', handleAnchor, false);
}
function handleAnchor(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(ajax) ajax.abort();
    ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onload = updateContent;
    ajax.open("get", this.href, true);
    ajax.send();
}
function updateContent() {
    // Do something with `this.responseText`
}
```

Comment: This code works exactly as expected! However, how would I go about also changing the URL (without reloading, lol) along with manage the forward and back buttons (all using javascript)? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @TimPowell To do that use the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Answer (score 1):

You can try a hash based url scheme:

```
someurl/#param1

someurl/#param2

...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i=0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    addEvent(anchors[i], 'click', preventDefault);
}

function preventDefault(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
   (e.preventDefault)? 
       e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
}

function addEvent(obj, evType, fn){ 
   if (obj.addEventListener){ 
       obj.addEventListener(evType, fn, false); 
       return true; 
   } 
   else if (obj.attachEvent){ 
       var r = obj.attachEvent("on"+evType, fn); 
       return r; 
 } else { 
       return false; 
 } 
}
```

Give this a try found this at [prevent default for all links inside a div using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677458/prevent-default-for-all-links-inside-a-div-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Try (this pattern) , utilizing jquery [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

html

```
<div class="1">content 1</div><div class="2">content 2</div>
<a class="1" href="#">update 1</a>
<a class="2" href="#">update 2</a>
```

js

```
$(function() {
var url = "http://example.org";
    $("a").each(function(i, el) {
        $(this).on("click", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
            if (i === 0) {
              $("div.1")
              .load(url + " #" + $(el).attr("class"));
             };
            if (i === 1) {
              $("div.2")
              .load(url + " #" + $(el).attr("class"));
            };
        })
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/dL4b4/

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
 $("a[href=#]").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
 })
```